# Auto-increment id field in djongo models (similar to djongo inherent collections)

Tags: mongodb, django-models, djongo

I am trying to create user profile collection in djongo. I tried to use similar pattern to the one used by djongo by having both _id and id:

_id:624572c73e01156f0d2b7491
id:4

However, I cannot find how this can be achieved, so any help would be greatly apraciated.

I tried the following to no avail:

```py
class Athlete(models.Model):

  # _id = models.ObjectIdField()
  # id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
  # id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID', editable=True, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self) -> str:
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

1. `id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')`

This option resulted in no id field at all in the database, only _id

2. `id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID', editable=False, unique=True)`

This resulted in id=Null

3. specifically specify both _id and id as ObjectIdField and AutoField

This resulted in error specifying only one auto filed is allowed

4. `id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)`

This resulted in errors while resolving reversed url due to the alphanumerical nature of uuid

5. I've seen a method specifying how to modify the **schema** collection in mongo, adding the id and seq to the auto object. The idea was clear but I failed to manually add the field to db collection, and at least in on case I have seen the seq advances but still being ignored by the program.

Answer (score 0):

Issue bypassed:

1. Recreated a new model identical to the original model, ran create migrations and migration to create the collection and update the **schema** collection.
2. Added the new model to admin.py and verified it manages the id field correctly (this time it did)
3. In compass - Entered the **schema**, deleted the old collection entry, replicated the new entry - modifying the name to the old collection name and the seq number in the auto field to the index of the id of the last item in the collection
4. Now the collection is managed correctly with the sequential id updated automatically
5. House cleaning removing all temporary models and collections

Remark: I am still unsure why the problem arose in the first place and why the auto portion of the collection in **schema** didn't include auto in the first place.